# How do I disable the category in custom fields in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I use a custom fields plugin for posts and use the review schema. I use it this way with a PHP extension.

the schema i used in the post:

[image]

code in php plugin:

```
    <?php
      $schema = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'schema', true);
      if(!empty($schema)){  
        echo $schema;
      }
    ?>
```

I use it in the elementor header like this:

```
[xyz-ips snippet="schemacode"]
```

My problem here is that I want this schema to appear only in the post, but it also appears in the post's categories. I tried this in if loop but it didn't work:

```
if(!empty($schema) && get_post_type() === 'post'){  
echo $schema;
}
```

How can I exclude categories? Thanks.

Comment: Solved.

if(!empty($schema) && is_single()){  
echo $schema;
}